# Python cassandra driver installation

Tags: python, shell, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have an installation shell script which installs the Cassandra python driver like below,

Source : https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/installation.html

```
#6) Install the Cassandra-Driver
echo "5) Install the cassandra-driver"
echo $password | sudo -S pip install cassandra-driver >/dev/null
echo "   Installed the cassandra-driver"
```

Now the problem is for the first time, `sudo -S pip install cassandra-driver`
is taking around 15 mins to install. Is there a better way to install this like local pip repository (or) Is it possible to package this so that I just want to unzip and run.

Answer (score 1):

It takes long because it compiles all code with Cython - you can either disable it with `--no-cython` (it will work, but will be slower.), or if you have all machines with same set of libraries, then you can build driver on one of them into form of `.egg` file, and then install from `.egg` (it requires `easy_install` installed).  This could be done with following commands

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py bdist_egg
sudo easy_install <path-to-egg-file>
```